# bungie.net stats api

Tags: json, api, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Has anyone tried accessing bungie.net reach stats api (statistics from Halo Matchmaking)?
As described here http://www.bungie.net/fanclub/statsapi/Group/Resources/Article.aspx?cid=545064

I can't seem to get any data returned, for example if i use this (with correct API key and gamertag values of course) ignore the first 2 asterisks ...

**http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/player/details/byplaylist/MyIdentifierAPIkey/Gamertag

I don't receive a response - but no errors either, am i doing something wrong?

looking to use this for a Titanium (appcelerator) app eventually.

Any help or advice welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: I too am curious about this...would love to do something with all that data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the API is not yet live to the public. I asked in a Private Message.  They didn't say when it would be live.

Answer (score 0):

In the Docs that Achronos posted, he put spaces in the URL's, I'm not sure if those are supposed to be there or not, so I tried it with the spaces and I got a 403 Forbidden error page.  When I remove all the spaces, I get an error page that says:

Request Error
The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

I kinda can't check the server logs though...  Bungie did say they were having some issues with the site though, so this might be a biproduct of that.  I want them to get it working soon though, I wanna see just what it can do!

Comment: .... thx for your reply, i thought maybe i was doing something wrong? and i tried all urls with and without spaces just to be sure, (there were in every one listed i noticed). I will keep checking the site and reply back to you if i notice anything new. thx again